# What will happen if I delete the logical partition from diskmgmt.msc?

Tags: partition

Anyone knows what it means exactly?

Comment: You might want to start accepting answers to some of your questions - the community is generally more helpful then. It's not the first time this has been suggested and you've had a lot of help from the community. It's the official way of saying thankyou.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will lose everything that is contained within that partition. Logical partitions are always located within an extended partition, so you will only lose the data that is on that partition, not the other partitions.

Comment: Will the deleted partition still be accessible ?

Comment: No. You can probably do recovery on the disk using recovery software if you discover you've done the wrong thing and you should get most of it back, but no, deleted is deleted.

Comment: If it's not accessible after deleting, what can be the purpose of doing this? I don't see a reason to do it then.

Comment: @wamp - you do it when you want to delete it, there's no hidden meaning. Perhaps you want to extend the previous partition?

Comment: You mean the additional space can be used to extend the other partition? How ?

Comment: If you're working with a Logical partition, the scenarios in which you can extend another partition to use its space are very slim (Becuase Logicals are only present inside Extended partitions, which were a basterdisation of the partition structure to begin with). But as MarkM said, you delete it when you don't want it any more.